# Is there a way to know that an ImgTileProvider has finished loading all tiles?

Tags: here-api

I'm building out a map app that pulls in tiles via an [`ImgTileProvider`](http://api.maps.nokia.com/en/apireference/2.2.1/symbols/nokia.maps.map.provider.ImgTileProvider.html). I would like to know when the tiles have been correctly loaded, but the only method exposed by the [`ImgTileProvider.Options`](http://api.maps.nokia.com/en/apireference/2.2.1/symbols/nokia.maps.map.provider.ImgTileProvider.Options.html) is the [`getUrl`](http://api.maps.nokia.com/en/apireference/2.2.1/symbols/nokia.maps.map.provider.ImgTileProvider.Options.html#getUrl) function, which helps me know *where* to get an image tile, not *when* it returns.

Is there an event that is fired after each tile/all tiles has/have been created/rendered to the page? I noticed that there was an `addListener` function available for `ImgTileProvider` instances, which I would subscribe to if I knew which event was being fired on image create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as I was writing this question, a thought occurred: why not check the source? Using Chrome, I prettified the `map-render-display.js` file and looked for events added via the `addListener` function. I didn't see anything for `ImgTileProvider`, but I found several other providers subscribing to a `response` event. So I added an event listener on my `ImgTileProvider` instance and it worked! Below is a sample of working code.

```js
// A magic number representing the total number of tiles in the map.
var magicNumber = 22;
// Returns a new ImgTileProvider.
tileProvider = self.imgTileProvider();
tileProvider.addListener("response", function () {
    magicNumber--;
    if (magicNumber === 0) {
        console.log("All tiles loaded");
    }
});
```